# How to save a plot at high resolution and then show it in the RMarkdown knitted file

Tags: r, image, r-markdown, knitr

Tried the following code:

```
png(filename = "forestv8aall.png",
    width = 2000,
    height = 1750,
    res = 135)

forest(allexpcollapsed,
       alim =c(-2, 4),
       xlim =c(-4, 5),
       ilab = totalexp$N.sample.size..post.attrition., 
       ilab.xpos = -2,
       xlab = "Omission-bias effect",
       cex = .8)

# Add headlines to the forest
op <- par(font=4)
text(-4,
     allexpcollapsed$k + 2,
     "Author(s), Year, and Study #",
     pos = 4,
     cex = .8)
text(5,
     allexpcollapsed$k + 2,
     "Observed [95% CI]",
     pos = 2,
     cex = .8)
text(-2,
     allexpcollapsed$k + 2,
     "Sample size",
     cex=.8)
par(op)
dev.off()
```

The below is shown in the RMD Knitted file:

```
## png 
##   2
```

I was able to see the output png file in the same folder though.

How to fix this so that the high-resolution plot is also shown in the RMD knitted word file?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using RStudio preferably (makes all of it much easier), create an Rmd file and put your R code in an R chunk. To display the image, simply use this syntax (this would be outside the R chunk):

```
![Optional replacement text](forestv8aall.png)
```

Then press on the "knit" button and voilà!